# How to avoid controller calling twice from div.load in ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am loading two partial views in my application. On click in the menu, calls the controller twice from div.load() in ajax call. How to avoid the controller calling twice.

**Jquery Ajax call :**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.common').click(function () {
                var pageid = this.id;
                LoadPartialView(pageid);
            });
        });

        function LoadPartialView(pageid) {
            alert('pass');
            var urls = '/WPindex/' + pageid + '/'
            $.ajax({
                url: urls,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/html',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divDefault').hide();                     
                    $('#divDynamic').load('/WPindex/' + pageid);                        
                }
            });
        }
```

**View**

```
<body>
    <div>
     <ul>
     <li><a id="MyAccount" class="common"><strong>Account Dashboard</strong></a></li>
     <li><a id="AccountDetails" class="common">Account Information</a></li>
     <li><a id="AddressBook" class="common">Address Book</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
     <div id="divDefault" class="order">     

     </div>
     <div id="divDynamic" class="order">
     </div>

</body>
```

**Controller**

```
  public ActionResult AccountDetails()
    {
       return PartialView();
    }
```

Here on click on the AccountDetails anchor tag, the partial view is loaded. But the controller is called twice. What is the mistake in my code.  ?
Any suggestions for bringing the partial view ??

Comment: First of all, close `<ul>` tag. Then, you get twice firing `click` event?

Comment: @FSoul1 : <ul> tag is added. I missed while pasting the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

```
$.ajax({
...
```

part makes the first call to the controller, and

```
success: function (result) {
    ...
    $('#divDynamic').load(...
```

makes the second one. If your task is just to load data in the div, you can get by with just one line:

```
$('#divDynamic').load('/WPindex/' + pageid);
```